# Get plain text from ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor, plaintext, vtiger

I want to know if it's possible to get plain text (text without html code) when I submit my form having a ckeditor textarea.

In fact, I want to have a simple textarea with the spellchecker option of ckeditor.

p.s. I am using vtiger 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, and given that you're using PHP a decent-ish solution would be [HTML Purifier.](http://htmlpurifier.org/) Assuming you can install it via PEAR (which is the most straightforward way to do it), your example would look like:

```
require_once 'HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML', 'Allowed', ''); // Allow Nothing
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
return $purifier->purify($_REQUEST['field_name']);
```

You're going to want to remove most of the editor buttons and other options from CKeditor as well to prevent your users from adding a lot of formatting that won't survive filtration.

**However:**

Using the full CKEditor stack for spellcheck is overkill! Why not just use a standalone, jQuery spellchecker [like this one?](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/)

Comment: hello, Thank you for the comment. Where I have to write it \ edit it? I forgot to mention that I use in CRM VTIGER 6 
Which file I need to edit there?

Comment: No idea. One imagines that as an open source project VTIGER 6 has documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function that strips HTML tags from a string, [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$plaintext = strip_tags($_POST['mytexteditor']);
```

You can also allow certain tags:

```
$plaintext_with_ps = strip_tags($_POST['mytexteditor'], '<p>');
```

Don't attempt to use it as a security measure, however.

Comment: strip_tags is not secure, comprehensive, or really very helpful at all.

Comment: he didn't ask about security

Comment: he shouldn't have to. providing a bad and insecure solution is worse than providing no solution at all.

Comment: I updated the answer. You're assuming he's trying to change HTML to plaintext for security reasons. I don't think that's the case.

Comment: At the very least, throw htmlspecialchars in there!